# Triggering events when clicking away from a focused Select2

Tags: jquery-select2

I have a need to capture an event (like a click) on a object that is elsewhere on the page and not a child of the select2 object while the select2 object has focus and is showing results.  When the select2 results object is focused, I cannot click on a button/anchor elsewhere on the page and have it perform its action.  It merely closes the select2 object.

Is there a way to do this?  Here is a demo that shows this behavior: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JoJobW

```
   <!-- Javascript snippet -->
   $(document).ready(function() { 
       $("#e1").select2(); 

       $("#e2").click(function(){
         alert("click!");
         e.preventDefault();
       });
   });

   <!-- HTML snippet -->
   <select id="e1"></select>
   <a href="#" id="e2">Click here when select2 is focused</a>
```

Using select2 v3.5.2 and jQuery 1.11.0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Select2 places a "mask" element behind the drop-down that captures the mouse click. [Others have complained](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/1715) about this.

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qL4jygyv/) that shows the mask element.

---

You could try to remove the mask element when the drop-down is opened.

```
$('#e1').select2().on('select2-open', function() {
    $('.select2-drop-mask').remove();
});
```

Of course, this means the drop-down will not close when the user clicks off of it, but you could add an event handler on the document (or body) to do that.

```
$(document).click(function() {
    $("#e1").select2('close');
});
```

You have to make sure the click event on the other element does not propagate to the document in that case.

```
$('#e2').click(function() {
    alert('click!');
    return false; // Prevent default action and stop propagation.
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uf3zutL5/)